# Next/Prev buttons to step through div contents

Tags: javascript

First of all a disclaimer, I'm not a dev. I'm halfway through [The Odin Project](https://www.theodinproject.com/) and have covered some HTML and CSS, but, have not yet started on JS. In order to help with my learning I've created [my own blog](https://onlyrss.org/). My aim is for each blog post to have its own stylesheet (so with each new post I learn a little more about CSS).

Anyway, I plan to write a post about the benefits of using an eReader, specifically the Kindle. I've styled the page to look like a Kindle Oasis, and I'd like the reader to be able to step through the article contents via the Kindle's next/prev buttons, but, as I'm not a dev, this is where I'm stuck. Via Stack overflow I've managed to add some JS that will display page 1, 2 and 3 via dedicated buttons for each dive element, but, what I really need is to step through x number of pages via the prev/next buttons.

Here's what I have so far: https://codepen.io/dbssticky/pen/yLVoORO. Any help would be much appreciated. What I should do of course is finish The Odin Project and come up with a solution on my own, but, I'd really like to get this Kindle article published sooner rather than later. Hence my rather cheeky request for assistance.

Here's the JS I'm currently using:

```
function swapContent(id) {
  const main = document.getElementById("main_place");
  const div = document.getElementById(id);
  const clone = div.cloneNode(true);
  while (main.firstChild) main.firstChild.remove();

  main.appendChild(clone);
}
```

Comment: Quick suggestion - you can dynamically create HTML elements using JS, put them in an array, and when the user clicks 'next', take the current index, add one, and display the new element. Or, instead of storing them in an array, you can also make the pages using HTML and CSS, keep track of the indices, and alter the `display` style on every button click to hide pages or make pages visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea and it just needs a few adjustments to get the previous/next functionality.

Currently your div IDs are following the format `operation1`, `operation2`, and so on. Since you want the previous/next functionality you'll need to change your 'swapping' function, which currently takes the full ID, to use the numeric portion only.

Add a new function which appends the number to 'operation' instead of using the whole thing:

```js
function goToPage(pageNumber){
  const main = document.getElementById("main_place");
  const div = document.getElementById("operation" + pageNumber);
  const clone = div.cloneNode(true);
  while (main.firstChild) main.firstChild.remove();

  main.appendChild(clone);
}
```

And then change your Page 1/2/3 buttons to use `goToPage(1)`, `goToPage(2)` and so on.

Now for the previous/next functionality you'll need a way to track which page you're on, so that you can figure out which page to load.

Add a variable at the top (outside functions)

```
var currentPage = 0;
```

Then add a line in your goToPage function to track the page you're on.

```
currentPage = pageNumber;
```

Now that you're tracking you can add a previous and next function.

```js
function goNextPage(){
  goToPage(currentPage-1);
}

function goPreviousPage(){
  goToPage(currentPage+1);
}
```

Then call it from the previous and next buttons.

```html
<button onClick="goNextPage()" class="next-button"></button>
<button onClick="goPreviousPage()" class="previous-button"></button>
```

Here's a codepen:  https://codepen.io/srirachapen/pen/WNZOXQZ

It's barebones and you may have to handle things like non existent div IDs.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<button class="next-button" onclick="nextContent()"></button>
<button class="previous-button" onclick="prevContent()"></button>
```

JS

```
var pageid = 0;
var maxpage = 3;
function nextContent() {
  if(pageid == maxpage) return
  pageid++
  swapContent(`operation${pageid}`)
  
}

function prevContent() {
  if(pageid == 1) return
  pageid--
  swapContent(`operation${pageid}`)
}
```

you can try this to switch between pages. But you may need to edit the "swapContent" method more sensibly.

Answer (score 0):

### **Track the Current Page**

Whatever solution you use to render pages & links (manual hardcoded links & content vs externally-stored & auto-generated), one thing is unavoidable: You need to track the current page!

```
var currentPage = 0
```

Then, any time there's a page change event, you update that variable.

With the current page being tracked, you can now perform operations relative to it (e.g. +1 or -1)

I'd suggest making a `goToPage(page)` function that does high-level paging logic, and keep your `swapContent()` function specifically for the literal act of swapping div content. In the future, you may find you'd want to use `swapContent()` for non-page content, like showing a "Welcome" or "Help" screen.

**Example:**

```
function goToPage(page) {

    // Update `currentPage`
    currentPage = page

    // ... other logic, like a tracking event or anything else you want you occur when pages change

    // Do the actual content swap, which could be your existing swapContent()
    swapContent('operation'+page)
}
```

You'd invoke the function like so:

```
goToPage(3) // Jump to a specific page
goToPage(currentPage + 1) // Go to the next page
goToPage(currentPage - 1) // Go to the prev page
```

You can make separate helper functions like "goToNextPage()" if you desire, but for sure you start with a fundamental page-change function first.